# Got stuck with Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm really having some issues with a mySql query:

Here is the tables:

Table Advise

```
idAdvise
IdObject1
IdObject2
IdUser
```

---

Table Objects

```
IdObject
title
image
```

---

Table Users

```
idUser
Username
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
advise.idAdvise | Objects.title AS Object1 | Objects.image AS ObjectImage1 | Objects.title AS Object2 | Objects.image AS ObjectImage2 | advise.idUser | users.username
```

Is it possible to have 2 different object info from object table with different id matching, where object1 refers to IdObject1 and object2 to IdObject2 ?

Or should I add those informations in the Advise table ?

Thanks anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a join where you join same table twice with different alias such as

```
Select 
    a.*, 
    o1.*, 
    o2.*, 
    u.* 
from advise a 
    left join object o1 
        on a.object1 = o1.objectid 
    left join object o2 
        on a.object2 = o2.objectid 
    left join user u 
        on a.userid = u.userid ....
```

this kind of join is possible, and solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped me out here. My Old mySql reminiscences are slowly coming back :)